# Calculating discount factor in java

Tags: java, android, math

I am trying to calculate monthly loan payments the formula Loan Payment = Amount / Discount Factor on [www.thebalance.com](https://www.thebalance.com/loan-payment-calculations-315564)
According to the website discount factor is calculated with this formula `(D) = {[(1 + i) ^n] - 1} / [i(1 + i)^n]` I tried interpreting this into Java and came up with

```
double discountFactor = (Math.pow((1 + interest), numberOfPayments) - 1) / Math.pow(interest * (1 + interest), numberOfPayments);
```

But it outputs `infinity`am not so good with Math, can someone help point out the issue?

Comment: If you get infinity, that means that `Math.pow(interest * (1 + interest), numberOfPayments)` is equal to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double discountFactor = (Math.pow((1 + interest), numberOfPayments) - 1) /
                        (interest  * Math.pow((1 + interest), numberOfPayments));
```

`interest` is not part of the power, it should be outside power.

Comment: awesome, went back to the formula and indeed interest wasn't part of the power.

Answer (score 0):

put the 'interest' outside the second power function not inside.

```
double discountFactor = (Math.pow((1 + interest),numberOfPayments)-1)/(interest*Math.pow((1+interest),numberOfPayments));
```